# Suppose that $p$ ≥ $q$ ≥ $5$ are both prime numbers. Prove that 24 divides ($p^2 − q^2$)

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-factorization

I suppose I need to use prime factorization. 
I want to show $p^2-q^2=24k$ for some integer $k$ . 
How can I start this proof?

Answer (score 7):

Hint: Show $p^2 = 1 \mod 3$ and $p^2 = 1 \mod 8$ for any such $p$.

Comment: You mean like show $p^2-1=3k$ , $k$ integer, and $p^2-1=8m$, $m$ is an integer?

Comment: But I don't have anything about $p$ except it is bigger than 5 and q.. I am so stuck

Comment: Use CRT to glue this two together, and you'll get $p^2 \equiv 1 \pmod {24}$, this holds for every prime number, so it also holds for $q^2$, so we have:

$$p^2 - q^2 \equiv 1 - 1 \equiv 0 \pmod {24} \implies p^2 - q^2 = 24k $$

Comment: @Wes Yes.. you know other things, that $p$ is odd and that $p = 1$ or $-1 \mod 3$. What does that mean in terms of $p^2$?

Comment: But $p$ is bigger than 5? How can it be 1?

Comment: $p\color{red}\equiv\pm1\pmod3$

Answer (score 2):

Like Stefan,

$$(6a\pm1)^2=36a^2\pm12a+1=24a^2+24\frac{a(a\pm1)}2+1\equiv1\pmod{24}$$ as the product of two consecutive integers is always even

Observe that $6a\pm1$ is not necessarily prime, but $(6a\pm1,6)=1$

So, any number $p$ relatively prime to $6$ will satisfy this

Answer (score 0):

It's well-known fact that every prime number, except for $2$ and $3$ can be written as $6k \pm 1$. SO we have:

$$(6k \pm 1)^2 - (6l \pm 1)^2 = 36k^2 \pm 12k + 1 - 36l^2 \mp 12l - 1$$

$$= 36(k^2-l^2) \pm 12(k - l) = 12(3k^2 - 3l^2 \pm k \mp l)$$

The sum in the parenthesis is always even. Why?

Hence we proved that it's divisible by 24.

Comment: Isn't 24 should be $24k$ $k$ integer?

Comment: You can look at the new, better solution. Is it clear to you?

Comment: Thanks. But this is not I did in the class. I don't even understand  $∓$

Comment: It's just same as $\pm$, indeed you can use $\pm$ instead of $\mp$, because the those two signs are independent and can be chosen freely.