# Does $n\mid(a^n-b^n)$ imply $n\mid(a-b)$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

> Given that $n,a,b \in  \mathbb{N}$ and $n\mid(a^n-b^n)$ , can we prove or disprove $n\mid(a-b)$ ?

Using Fermat's little theorem, we can prove the case when *n* is a prime number. What about the case when *n* is a composite number?
I also know that $(a-b)\mid(a^n-b^n)$ .

Comment: For composite $n$ the claim is not necessarily true. Check $n=4,a=3,b=1$ as an example.

Comment: @Linear, you should approve suggested title.

Comment: @MithleshUpadhyay I don't want to repeat the sentence in the content. We can still search the question with the text in the content.

Comment: @Linear, That's valid edit to right click.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can prove $$8|(p^2-q^2)$$ where $p,q$ are odd

But we can easily choose $p\not\equiv q\pmod 8$

Comment: And hence $8\mid (p^8-q^8).$

Comment: See also : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/525947/suppose-that-5-leq-q-leq-p-are-both-prime-prove-that-24p2-q2

Comment: @awllower, Yes as $$(p^2)^4-(q^2)^4$$ is divisible by $p^2-q^2$

Comment: I just commented as a complement. :D

Comment: @awllower, I just added the explanation :)

Answer (score 0):

We have $$a^n-b^n = (a-b)\left(a^{n-1} + a^{n-2}b+a^{n-3}b^2+\dots+ab^{n-2} + b^{n-1}\right)$$
So, if $n|(a^n-b^n)$, it is not necessarily true that $n|(a-b)$.

Comment: Please join this chat room http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43905/n-s-john-and-aritra-das