# How to prove Prime numbers can be expressed as $6k\pm 1$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I am reading some post in 
[Suppose that $5\leq q\leq p$ are both prime. Prove that $24|(p^2-q^2)$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/525947/suppose-that-5-leq-q-leq-p-are-both-prime-prove-that-24p2-q2)

and

[Suppose that $p$ ≥ $q$ ≥ $5$ are both prime numbers. Prove that 24 divides ($p^2 − q^2$)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/507451/suppose-that-p-%E2%89%A5-q-%E2%89%A5-5-are-both-prime-numbers-prove-that-24-divides-p2)

In some of their answer, they mention that some prime $p$ can be expressed as $6k\pm 1$ without proof.

For some few examples i see this, but how i can prove for large $p$?

5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, ...

can you give me some proof for this statement?

Comment: $1$ is not prime.

Comment: Please edit the question since 1 is *not* a prime number, as mentioned by other users.

Comment: @ i 8 Σ π_821, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All other numbers are either

1. $6k\pm2$, and therefore divisible by $2$
2. $6k+3$ and therefore divisible by $3$
3. $6k$, and therefore divisible by $6$

So if the prime is neither $2$ nor $3$, it cannot belong to any of the categories above. $6k\pm 1$ is what is left.

Answer (score 1):

$6k$, $6k\pm2$, and $6k\pm3$ are all composite (divisible by 6, 2, and 3, respectively). Thus the primes must be of form $6k\pm1$.

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) when writing mathematics on this site. It looks _much_ better.

Comment: Use the \pm option to do the plus or minus symbol Like this $\pm$. Don't forget the dollar signs as well.

Comment: I edited the answer. Waiting for approval.

Comment: I cannot approve yet since I don't have enough rep.

Comment: I have approved Jason's edit.