# Expression of Prime numbers via $ak\pm b$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

This is extension of my previous question 
[How to prove Prime numbers can be expressed as $6k\pm 1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2197832/how-to-prove-prime-numbers-can-be-expressed-as-6k-pm-1#2197840)

The main answer from the post is list all $6k\pm1, 6k \pm2, 6k +3, $ and see wheter it can be decompose into other numbers, $i.e$, $2$ or $3$.

At this stage, i have a question why $6$?

How about 4, 5, 7, or any other numbers and forms like $ak+b$?

Is there any reason for $6$?

Comment: If you understand the logic behind the answers to the other question, you may apply it to 4, 5, 7, and see what happens.

Comment: You *can* continue to do this indefinitely.  All primes (except for 2 and 3) are of the fork $36k \pm i$ where $i$ is $1,5,7,11,13,17$.  That's just not as pithy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To have $ak \pm m $ describe all primes, then $m $ and $a-m $ must be the only two numbers smaller than $a$ that are relatively prime to $a $.

For $2$, $2k+1$ covers all primes (except 2) because the only other cases are $2k $ and those are composite (except 2).

Same with $3k\pm 1$.  The only other case is $3k $.

$4k\pm 1$ describes all primes (except 2) because the only other case is $4k$ and $4k +2$.  But $2$ is not relatively prime to $4$ so all $4k+2$ will be composite.

We can't do anything with $5k \pm i $.  $5k$ must be composite, but as $1,2,3,4$ are all relatively prime to $5$ we can't say any of the $5k+i $ must be composite.  $5k+i $ *could* be prime for all $1,2,3,4$.

$6k \pm 1$ describe all primes because none of $i=0,2,3,4$ are relatively prime to $6$ so all $6k +i $ are composite.

We can't do anything with $7k \pm m $ because all $i=1,2,3,4,5,6$ are realitively prime so none of $7k+i $ must be composite.

For $8$ $8k\pm 1$ and $8k\pm 3$ describe all primes (except 2) because all other $i=0,2,4,6$ are not relatively prime to $8$ so $8k+i $ must be composite.  But $\pm 1$ and $\pm 3$ are both relatively prime so we need both of them and we can't make this a single expression.

And for no other number higher than $6$, can we have only *one* pair of relatively prime numbers.  So $6k\pm1$ is the last such single expression that describes all primes.

Comment: Wow, your answer bright my concern. Thanks for clarifying this problem with detail explanation!