# If $(6,n)=1$, prove that $n^2-1$ is divisible by $24$.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

If $(6,n)=1$, prove that $n^2-1$ is divisible by $24$.

Comment: Okay, what are your thoughts on this so far? What exactly is your question?

Comment: I assume this means $\gcd(6,n)=1$?

Comment: Most (if not all) of the proofs in the dupe apply here (even though the title restricts to primes $> 3)\ $

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

$$(6,n)=1\implies$$
$ n=6k+1 $ or $n=6k-1$.

in the first case

$$n^2-1=36k^2+12k=12k(3k+1)$$

in the second

$$n^2-1=12k(3k-1).$$

If $k$ is even ....

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/507451/suppose-that-p-≥-q-≥-5-are-both-prime-numbers-prove-that-24-divides-p2/507511#507511

Answer (score 0):

If $(6,n) =  1,$ then $n \equiv 1 \pmod 6$ or $n \equiv 5 \pmod 6,$ since $\varphi(6) = 2.$ 
So, we have two cases:

► $n \equiv 1 \pmod 6:$
$$n \equiv 1 \pmod 6 \Rightarrow n^2 \equiv 1^2 \pmod 6 \Rightarrow n^2 - 1 \equiv 0 \pmod 6 \Rightarrow \boxed{n^2 - 1 \equiv 0 \pmod{24}}$$

► $n \equiv 5 \pmod 6 \Rightarrow n \equiv -1 \pmod 6:$
$$n \equiv -1 \pmod 6 \Rightarrow n^2 \equiv (-1)^2 \pmod 6 \Rightarrow n^2 - 1 \equiv 0 \pmod 6 \Rightarrow \boxed{n^2 - 1 \equiv 0 \pmod{24}}$$

In both, we conclude that $n^2 - 1 \equiv 0 \pmod{24}.$ Therefore, $n^2 - 1$ is divisible by $24$ when $(6,n) =  1.$

Answer (score 0):

$(6,n)=1$  $\implies$  $n$ is odd.
Therefore , $$n^{2}\equiv 1 \pmod8$$
Also $(3,n)=1$ , since $(2\times3,n)=1$ 
Therefore by Fermat's theorem ,$$n^2\equiv 1\pmod3$$.
Now you can directly combine these two congruences, since $(3,8)=1$

Therefore,  $$n^2\equiv 1\pmod{24}$$